# Workspace switcher only shows 1x4 grid and no animations

Tags: workspaces

I did a fresh install of 11.10. Since then the workspace switcher shows no switching animation (including the small 2x2 preview when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow key</kbd>). All I see is a plain 1x4 grid of workspaces.

[image: CompizConfig Settings Manager]

Also, when switching to another workspace, all windows get maximised every time.
Messing with the CCSM options gave me no result. This never happened in 11.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Unity 2D, thats why the *CompizConfig Settings Manager* has no effects, Compiz simply isn't being used.

Are there any proprietary drivers available for your system? You can check it with Jockey (the *Additional hardware drivers* dialog). If yes, select the one saying *recommended* and hit the *Install* or *Activate* button.
[image: Jockey (old, but English)]
[image: Jockey]

Comment: So I had an issue where my graphics driver was not shown in the proprietary drivers settings. So I installed it manually, restarted my pc and finally everything works as it should. Thanks!